# Em requests, como ler corretamente o encoding ISO-8859-1?

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Em Python3, com beautifulsoup4 e requests, quero extrair algumas informações de um site que possui encoding 'ISO-8859-1'. Tentei essa estratégia para mostrar corretamente o texto:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://sisgvarmazenamento.blob.core.windows.net/prd/PublicacaoPortal/Arquivos/201901.htm')
req.encoding

encoding = req.encoding
text = req.content

decoded_text = text.decode(encoding)

sopa = BeautifulSoup(decoded_text, "lxml")

sopa.find("h1")
```

E o resultado que aparece é:

```
<h1>
                        CÃMARA MUNICIPAL DE SÃO PAULO<br/></h1>
```

Quando copio e colo nesta tela aparece correto, mas no meu computador toda a acentuação está errada

Estou em uma máquina com Ubuntu

Por favor, alguém sabe uma forma correta de ler o encoding?

---

Editado 2 de junho de 2019

Tive a ajuda de @snakecharmerb [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385353/how-to-find-out-the-correct-encoding-when-using-beautifulsoup/56404834#56404834)

Na resposta ele detalhou que quando o nenhum charset explícito estiver presente nos cabeçalhos HTTP e o cabeçalho Content-Type contiver texto, o o RFC 2616 especifica que o conjunto de caracteres padrão deve ser ISO-8859-1. Que é o caso deste site

Mas claramente as palavras são UTF-8, então corrijo manualmente e funciona
Meu código ficou assim e funcionou:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://sisgvarmazenamento.blob.core.windows.net/prd/PublicacaoPortal/Arquivos/201901.htm')
req.encoding

'ISO-8859-1'

req.headers['content-type']
'text/html'

req.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sopa = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')

sopa.find('h1').text
'\r\n                        CÂMARA MUNICIPAL DE SÃO PAULO'
```

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade, o `requests` já faz a decodificação pra você,usando o encoding correto.

É só em vez de acessar o atributo `.content`, acessar o atributo `.text` do objeto "response":

```
In [382]: import requests                                                                                              

In [383]: data = requests.get("https://slashdot.org")                                                                  

In [384]: type(data.content)                                                                                           
Out[384]: bytes

In [385]: type(data.text)                                                                                              
Out[385]: str
```

Mas entender de encodnig e não ficar chutando o que acontece é meio *vital* nessa indústria. Eu não canso de recomendar o seguinte artigo, escrito originalmente em 2003 pelo criador do StackOverflow:

[O Mínimo Absoluto Que Todos os Programadores de Software Precisam, Absolutamente, Positivamente de Saber Sobre Unicode e Conjuntos de Caracteres (Sem Desculpas!)](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!))

Comment: Obrigado @jsbueno. Eu fiz a requisição -> req = requests.get('https://sisgvarmazenamento.blob.core.windows.net/prd/PublicacaoPortal/Arquivos/201901.htm')

Comment: Depois o beautifulsoup com text -> sopa = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

Comment: Mas o resultado ficou com erro na tela na acentuação, o mesmo -> sopa.find("h1") - CÃMARA MUNICIPAL DE SÃO PAULO

Comment: Apesar de quando copio aqui o erro não aparece. É isso que apontei acima

Comment: você está usando Python 2? por que em Python 3, ele deveria cuidar da codificação do terminal automaticamente pra você. Se for Python 2 você tem dois problemas - o do encoding, e o problema de estar usando Python 2.

Comment: ah, agora vi qu você está no ubuntu, e não no windows - veja nas configurações do seu terminal, se ele está usando utf-8 (o requests lida com o encoding legado latin-1 (iso-8859-1), daí pra frente voce tem unicode. se tentou mudar o encoding do temrinal, pode estar confundindo o python)

Comment: Muito obrigado @jsbueno. Um outro colega me ajudou aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385353/how-to-find-out-the-correct-encoding-when-using-beautifulsoup/56404834#56404834

Comment: Ele me explicou que quando o nenhum charset explícito estiver presente nos cabeçalhos HTTP e o cabeçalho Content-Type contiver texto, o o RFC 2616 especifica que o conjunto de caracteres padrão deve ser ISO-8859-1. Que é o caso deste site

Comment: Mas claramente as palavras são UTF-8, então corrijo manualmente e funciona. Vou alterar acima com o resultado que funcionou para mim

Answer (score 0):

Se você se refere em exibir no terminal ou prompt de comando do windows então para resolver você deve setar no script python o charset, assim:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...
```

Se a página estiver em iso-8859-1 ou windows-1252, se estiver em utf-8 use assim:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...
```

Me parece que a página que linkou esta em utf-16, então creio que seria assim:

```
# -*- coding: utf-16 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...
```

Comment: Na verdade isso está 100% incorreto. A indicação do charset no código fonte serve para os caractéres acentuados no próprio arquivo .py, não para dados lidos de uma fonte externa, como um arquivo, ou, nesse caso, uma requisição HTTP.

Comment: @jsbueno mas eu não disse que o problema era no HTTP, falei exatamente outra coisa, é o `requests` quem baixa os dados e o `BeautifulSoup` quem decodifica e provavlemente já resolve isto, o problema é que o site esta vindo em utf-16 (foi o que me pareceu) e o script esta em outra. Tudo bem até parte da resposta pode estar errada, mas com certeza o que vc afirmou no comentário não foi o que eu disse, e vou revisar a resposta aqui.

Comment: 100% incorreto , e talvez mais, já que você insiste no erro.
essa marcação é só para o _compilador_ do Python, na hora de ler o arquivo.py e gerar o bytecode.  Não interfere em como strings são mostradas em qualquer terminal . isso só mudaria o aspecto de uma string digitada direto no código.